# esp8266 getting data from thingspeak by using IPD answer

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

i am new here, if asked before sorry in advance,
i cannot found a related question.

I edited a code for get the thingspeak channel's data, for using with a led or relay on channel 8 on arduino uno. according to data 1 or 0, the led would be on or off. I am using esp8266.

espSerial.find("+IPD,1:0") block is cannot work as it needed to do.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial espSerial(2, 3);   
#define DEBUG true
String mySSID = "ssid";
String myPWD = "pass"; 
String myAPI = "CV4YEARDB91GTOXM";   // API Key
String myHOST = "api.thingspeak.com";
String myPORT = "80";
String myFIELD = "field1";

void setup()
{
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  espSerial.begin(115200);

  espData("AT+RST", 1000, DEBUG);                     
  espData("AT+CWMODE=1", 1000, DEBUG);                 
  espData("AT+CWJAP=\""+ mySSID +"\",\""+ myPWD +"\"", 1000, DEBUG);   
  delay(1000); }

void loop()
  {

    String sendData = "GET /channels/716457/fields/1/last?key=CV4YEARDB91GTOXM";
    espData("AT+CIPMUX=1", 1000, DEBUG);
    espData("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\""+ myHOST +"\","+ myPORT, 1000, DEBUG);
    espData("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(sendData.length()+4),1000,DEBUG);
    espSerial.find(">");
    espSerial.println(sendData);

    espData("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",1000,DEBUG);
    delay(10000);
  }

String espData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
Serial.print(command);
  Serial.println("     ");

  String response = "";
  espSerial.println(command);
  long int time = millis();
  while ( (time + timeout) > millis())
  {
    while (espSerial.available())
    {
      if (espSerial.find("+IPD,1:0")) {
        digitalWrite(8,LOW); }
      if (espSerial.find("+IPD,1:1")) {
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH); }
    }
    }

  if (debug)
  {
    Serial.print(response);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: "is cannot work as it needed to do" is not a valid problem report.  You need to be specific about what exactly happens.  Consider tapping the serial line between processors to monitor it, and beware that serial communication is hard to get right since there are many thought error pitfalls which can be made especially with regard to the time between characters being faster or slower than assumed.  What have you done to even determine that you have successfully joined a wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for my intention which is get data from thingspeak channel by using +IPD answer:

```
    String espData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
    {
    Serial.print(command);
      Serial.println("     ");

      String response = "";
      espSerial.println(command);
      long int time = millis();
      while ( (time + timeout) > millis())
      {
        if (espSerial.available()>0)
        {      
          if (espSerial.find("+IPD,0,1:")); {
            while (espSerial.available()>0) {
          String gelen = "";
          char serialdenokunan;

          serialdenokunan = espSerial.read();
          gelen += serialdenokunan;
          Serial.println(gelen);
          if (gelen.indexOf("0")>=0) {
            digitalWrite(8,LOW); }
          if (gelen.indexOf("1")>=0) {
            digitalWrite(8,HIGH); }
        }}}
        }

      if (debug)
      {
        Serial.print(response);
      }
      return response;
   }
```

In case single connection which AT+CIPMUX=0, than IPD answer would be +IPD,0:data instead of +IPD,0,connectionnumber:data. Than if (espSerial.find("+IPD,0:")) works in that case.

Thanks for everyone who answered via message and post.

Answer (score 0):

There is easier method to do this.
ThingSpeak has created library on [GitHub](https://github.com/mathworks/thingspeak-arduino) which will handle both writing and reading data to/from ThingSpeak channels. You could try an example which was included in the library.